# How to change/discount total amount before payment

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce

I want to change the total amount programatically before the payments are processed.

If the total amount is $1000 I want to give a discount based on a point system in the users profile. You can add the desired amount based on his total points. If he adds 20 he gets a $20 discount and only have to pay $800.

What is the best way to implement this? I have tried with `commerce_transactions.onCreateTransaction` but no luck.

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked into building an adjuster for this purpose? You can find the documentation [here](https://craftcommerce.com/docs/adjusters)